# Is the phrase "come fast" a grammatically correct imperative?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, adverbs, imperatives

Is the following sentence grammatically correct as a command?

> "Come fast."

I believe this would be a correct alternative:

> "Come quick."

Comment: Come fast, before the cookies are all gone!

Comment: It might depend on which English-speaking country you are in.  It doesn't sound correct to my British ears (except in a sexual context!).  If you mean you want someone to come to your location very quickly, I would say "come quickly".  "Come quick" grates with me, because the phrase requires an adverb ("quickly") not an adjective ("quick").

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what was intended. To invite people to participate in a religious practice of not eating, “come fast” works but “come quick” doesn’t.

*Grammar that doesn’t consider intent* is a low bar to cross. If a sentence conveys meaning in some context - any context - it’s grammatical. And some would say that’s already too high a standard for grammaticality.

Comment: Ah, but "Come quick" could mean "Don't come dead". ;-)

Comment: @BoldBen Aye. :)

Answer (score 2):

Let me ease any discomfort you might feel with *come fast* as an imperative. The source of that discomfort is probably that you think of *fast* as adjective rather than adverb. It can indeed be an adjective, as applied to a runner, a car, or (in a sexist pejorative sense) a woman. But it can also be an adverb, as in *He ran fast.*

The horror of using an adjective where an adverb (perhaps one ending in *-ly)* seems required is often overblown. Before yielding to it, one should remember not only the New Hampshire license-plate motto "Live free or die" but also the opening line of *Lamentations* in the King James Version: "How doth the city sit solitary, that was full of people!"

Comment: My quick-running stopwatch endorses this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is grammatical. You can use the the idiom:  **come thick and fast**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+thick+and+fast)

> To come rapidly and in large quantities (as in an attack).

And,  **come quick** or **come quickly** works too.  It all depends on context and sentence structure.

*- Leona, come quick!
 - They come fast at times too.
 - Papa, Papa, come quickly!*